# How to display array from Parse in a tableView

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

In Parse, I have a class called `Queries`. In this class I have a column that is of array type called `favorites` I would like to display that array in a `UITableView` The trouble is that the query downloads the `favorites` array column as one array, instead of multiple.
For example:
Row 1 has `["Bananas"]` in favorites column
Row 2 has `["Apples", "Oranges"]` in favorites column.
Row 3 has `["Tomatoes"]` in favorites column

I would like the `tableView` to show:
Bananas
Apples, Oranges
Tomatoes

But now its showing:
Bananas
Apples
Oranges

```
var favorites : [String] = []  

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Queries")
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (object, error) in
          if object != nil && error == nil {
            if let returnedObjects = object {
              for objects in returnedObjects {
               let getFavorites = objects["favorites"] as! [String]
                 self.favorites.append(contentsOf: getFavorites)

                   self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
```

The tableView is populated like this:  `cell.favoritesLabel.text = favorites[indexPath.row]`

Comment: check out the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Your `favourites` variable is a single dimension array, so you should either join values from a single row, or make it a two dimensional array and handle it appropriately.
To join values replace your `append` line with this one:

```
self.favorites.append(getFavorites.joined(separator: ", "))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all change your `favorites` array to this

```
var favorites: [[String]] = []
```

And change this `self.favorites.append(contentsOf: getFavorites)`
 To this `self.favorites.append(getFavorites)`

The mistake is that you are appending `string` to an array of `strings` ignoring that they came in an `array` in the first place,
now after that you can reduce your items to one string to set it in the `cell` 
like this

```
cell.favoritesLabel.text = (favorites[indexPath.row])[1..<array.count].reduce(array[0]) { $0 + ", " + $1 }
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Although not strictly relevant to your question, I thought I would mention that the Parse iOS SDK does provide a set of prebuilt UI elements one of which is `PFQueryTableViewController`.

If you haven't already, it may be worth taking a look at the [`PFQueryTableViewController` section in the docs](http://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#pfquerytableviewcontroller) to see if that would simplify your implementation in this case.